# Handling large number of Tasks in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, task-parallel-library, bindinglist

I have a BindingList<> of objects bound to a DataGridView. These objects contain a foreign key for another object, and some of the columns of the first object are meant to show a read-only field from the foreign key object.

I thought I could keep a copy of the foreign object as a private variable, and if this was null, I would make a fetch request to the webservice to obtain the foreign object, then call NotifyPropertyChanged() on the relevant fields to indicate that the foreign object has been loaded and to update those fields in the DataGridView.

This works -- to a point. For large numbers of records, it seems some tasks run and never return, even when cancelled. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
    private ForeignObj _foreignObject = null;
    public string ForeignName
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_foreignKey.HasValue)
                return null;

            if (_foreignObject == null)
            {
                GetForeignObject(); // method is async, so it spawns a task and returns immediately
                return "Fetching...";
            }

            return _foreignObject.Name;
        }
    }

    CancellationTokenSource foreignObjectToken = null;
    public async Task GetForeignObject()
    {
        if (foreignObjectToken != null)
            return; // Don't call it again while it is already fetching

        foreignObjectToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        foreignObjectToken.CancelAfter(10000); // Don't let request go longer than 10 seconds

        _foreignObject = await DTOPropertyHelper.GetForeignObject(_foreignKey.Value, foreignObjectToken.Token); // HTTP request to web service to obtain foreign object

        OnPropertyChanged("ForeignName");
        foreignObjectToken = null;
    }
```

Update: I find that this 'works' in the property getter, but is ugly:

```
get
{
    if (!_foreignKey.HasValue)
        return null;

    if (_foreignObject == null)
    {
        if (DTOPropertyHelper.NumTasks < DTOPropertyHelper.MaxTasks)
            GetForeignObject();
        else
            OnPropertyChanged("ForeignName");

        return null;
    }

    return _foreignObject.Name;
}
```

...Essentially constantly firing a PropertyChanged event which continues to hammer the task creation providing less than the MaxTasks number is valid (DTOPropertyHelper.GetForeignObject() automatically increments and decrements NumTasks).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have more properties like `ForeignName` showing fields of your `_foreignObject`? Then you have a *race condition* between creating your `foreignObjectToken` and checking it for `null`, because your `async` method is already a `Task` (means it runs in its own thread). If that's the case, you should protect the `foreignObjectToken` with a `lock`:

```
Object foreignObjectTokenLock = new Object();
CancellationTokenSource foreignObjectToken = null;
public async Task GetForeignObject()
{
    lock (foreignObjectTokenLock)
    {
        if (foreignObjectToken != null)
            return; // Don't call it again while it is already fetching
        foreignObjectToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
    foreignObjectToken.CancelAfter(10000); // Don't let request go longer than 10 seconds

    _foreignObject = await DTOPropertyHelper.GetForeignObject(_foreignKey.Value, foreignObjectToken.Token); // HTTP request to web service to obtain foreign object

    OnPropertyChanged("ForeignName");
    // I guess there should be some more OnPropertyChanged()?
    foreignObjectToken = null;
}
```

I have to add that it's unclear to me how this race condition would lead to Tasks not returning at all (except the web service call could somehow hang forever), so maybe this isn't yet the *whole* solution.

Comment: I do in one case, but not in others. Strangely enough, if I add the lock, then the whole program freezes.
See my edit above for a very odd 'solution' thus far.